# apply for loop on json response (multidimensional) to get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{
  "Search": [{
    "Title": "Batman Begins",
    "Year": "2005",
    "imdbID": "tt0372784",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }, {
    "Title": "Batman",
    "Year": "1989",
    "imdbID": "tt0096895",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwNjAyODIyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDMwMDk2._V1_SX300.jpg"
  }],
  "totalResults": "291",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

Above is my json response. I want to get title values by using jQuery.

I tried below code... I'm sending request each time when user insert character in text box (on `keyup`):

```
url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + value;
$.getJSON(url, {
  get_param: 'value'
}, function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, element) {
    //console.log(data);   
  });
  for (var prop in data) {
    var item = data[prop];
    for (var d in item) {
      var title = item[d];
      console.log(title);
    }

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jquery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to iterate over both arrays and object.
It takes to arguments either array or object as the first argument and a callback function.
since the response is in form of an object you need to run another `Jquery.each()` on the array holding the objects if you want to implement some logic before that, or just run `Jquery.each()` on the array it's self:

Here is a sample code that prints the titles on the console:

```
$.getJSON(url, { get_param: 'value' }, function(data) {
            $.each(data.Search, function(index, value) {
              console.log(value.Title);
            });

        });
```

And here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1nckLsL6/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle i'll poke it a bit to achieve the functionality you desire, if you think of something else let me know

Comment: I upodated the answer and provided you with a working JSFIddle that prints all the titles to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.Search, function(obj){          
   alert(obj.Title);
});
```